# How to exclude field conditionaly?

Tags: django, django-import-export

I need to exclude `id_from_integration` if `Company.integration_enabled == False`.

My resource and model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    integration_enabled = models.BooleanField()


class Report(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)


class ReportResource(resources.ModelResource):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ('name', 'id_from_integration', ...)
```

Comment: is this for import, export or both?

Comment: @MatthewHegarty export only

Comment: for now I just created separate resource class and use it conditionaly

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?
Note you cannot exclude the column completed because of the cases when `Company.integration_enabled == True`.  When `False`, return an empty string.

```py
class CustomField(Field):
    def export(self, report):
        if not report.company.id_from_integration:
            return ""
        return super().export(obj)


class ReportResource(resources.ModelResource):
    
    # set column_name to the column name in the import
    id_from_integration = CustomField(attribute="id_from_integration", 
        column_name="id_from_integration", widget=widgets.BooleanWidget())
    
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ('name', 'id_from_integration', ...)
```

I expect your export will look something like this:

```
id_from_integration        |name         |id
---------------------------|-------------|--
True                       |             |1 
                           |             |12
                           |             |13
```